# Uninstalling Node.js On a Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, shell

So I installed Node.js by downloading the mac 0Sx package from their website, but now every time I try to run a command such as `f$ grunt-cli -v` I get the following error below. This path `/usr/local/bin/npm` also doesn't exist on my computer, and I don't know how to find node.js to unistall it, and then re-install it using homebrew. Let me know if I have left any info out.

```
-bash: grunt-cli: command not found
Sams-MacBook-Pro:~ SamDavidoff$ npm install -g grunt-cli
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/SamDavidoff/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 3):

`EACCES` means you don't have root access. Reinstalling node/npm won't help. Like it says, try running it as admin:

```
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Or if you don't want to use `sudo`, install [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) (note nvm may not allow you to globally install on mac, but it does on ubuntu so it might work):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/creationix/nvm.git ~/.nvm && cd ~/.nvm && git checkout `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`
$ ...
$ ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
$ ...
$ nvm install stable
$ ...
$ nvm use stable
$ npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Comment: But isn't slightly wreckless to install things by overriding all permissions or is it common?

Comment: @user3236637 it isn't really "overriding" since root access is required to install things globally.

Answer (score 0):

`bash sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm /usr/local/share/man/man1/node* /usr/local/lib/dtrace/node.d ~/.npm ~/.node-gyp`

this should work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).